# Concatenating string by rows in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am having a pyspark dataframe as

```
DOCTOR | PATIENT
JOHN   | SAM
JOHN   | PETER
JOHN   | ROBIN
BEN    | ROSE
BEN    | GRAY
```

and need to concatenate patient names by rows so that I get the output like:

```
DOCTOR | PATIENT
JOHN   | SAM, PETER, ROBIN
BEN    | ROSE, GRAY
```

Can anybody help me regarding creating this dataframe in pyspark ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to use `collect_list`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.groupby("col1").agg(f.concat_ws(", ", f.collect_list(df.col2)))
```

Comment: Thanks Assaf ! Will this replace the existing column or create a new column ? My intention is to create a new column.

Comment: This will create a dataframe with only two columns, col1 and col2 aggregated as this is an aggregate function.

Comment: Hi @Assaf, thanks for the clarification. While I am putting df.col2 in the above statement, its not retaining the order of col2 in mind while concatenating.

For e.g. 
if I take the same example as in the question, and need the result as 
JOHN  |  PETER, ROBIN, SAM
BEN    |   GRAY, ROSE
i,e. alphabetically sorted, what changes should I make to the statement ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: if you need to sort inside a key, what I would do is do just the collect_list part, without concatenating, then do a UDF which gets the list, sorts it and creates the string. It will be slower though and involve more than a single line

Comment: The problem with this is that when you call `collect_list` on a single string, it converts the splits the string by character.

Comment: @frosty I am not sure what you mean, collect_list collects values from different rows, it should never be called on a string

Comment: Yeah, I ended up getting it to work, however the aggregated column is not the same for every key. If a key only has row after the group by, the row will look like 
`key1    value1` but if the key has more than one value, it is wrapped in quotes like 
`key1    "value1,value2"`

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

data = [
  ("U_104", "food"),
  ("U_103", "cosmetics"),
  ("U_103", "children"),
  ("U_104", "groceries"),
  ("U_103", "food")
]
schema = StructType([
  StructField("user_id", StringType(), True),
  StructField("category", StringType(), True),
])
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("groupby").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
group_df = df.groupBy(f.col("user_id")).agg(
  f.concat_ws(",", f.collect_list(f.col("category"))).alias("categories")
)
group_df.show()
```

```
+-------+--------------------+
|user_id|          categories|
+-------+--------------------+
|  U_104|      food,groceries|
|  U_103|cosmetics,childre...|
+-------+--------------------+
```

There are some useful aggregation examples

- [pyspark dataframe aggregation examples](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/using-groupby-on-dataframe/)

Comment: Try adding some more commentary to what's actually going on, thanks devsheprherd

Answer (score 0):

Using Spark SQL this worked for me:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(collect_list(col4) AS string),"[",""),"]","")
FROM your_table
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```