# How to use join text with group by in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, group-by, aggregate

I have a pyspark dataframe

| id | events |
| --- | --- |
| a0 | a-markets-l1 |
| a0 | a-markets-watch |
| a0 | a-markets-buy |
| c7 | a-markets-z2 |
| c7 | scroll_down |
| a0 | a-markets-sell |
| b2 | next_screen |

I am trying to join events by grouping IDs
Here's my python code

```
df_events_userpath = df_events.groupby('id').agg({ 'events': lambda x: ' '.join(x)}).reset_index()
```

| id | events |
| --- | --- |
| a0 | a-markets-l1 a-markets-watch a-markets-buy a-markets-sell |
| c7 | a-markets-z2 scroll_down |
| b2 | next_screen |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating string by rows in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788919/concatenating-string-by-rows-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using collect_set

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(f.collect_set("events").alias("events"))
```